# REST API Custom atribute from AD

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, active-directory

I have REST API url: http://siteURL.com/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Manager')?@v='[%Variable:user%]'

It works for me for propertyName = Manager
I need to get other field through similar REST API call named "extensionAttribute1" which is Exchange atribute in Active Directory. I tried to change "Manager" to "extensionAttribute1" in URL above, but it gives me no value.

I work with SharePoint Online.

Could you help me, please?

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution on this site: https://prasadpathak.wordpress.com/tag/unable-to-deserialize-http-response-content/

Problem was that the workflow was Suspended with message: 
Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.IO.InvalidDataException: Unable to deserialize HTTP response content. Expected ContentType : 'application/json', 'text/plain' or 'text/html', Received ContentType : 'application/xml'.  ...

To solve this problem you need to build a Dictionary with two variables, NOT ONLY ONE "Accept". You have to create variable "Content-Type" too.

Hope it helps someone :)